# Conjugaison. Lorsque l’on utilise « on »

Tags: grammaire, prononciation, conjugaison, oral, passé-composé

Il y a quelques mois que je suis  étudiant en France et, parfois, pendant mes cours j’entend le professeur dire des choses comme « On avez trouvé ce résultat » ou « On avez vu que cette formule...»

La question que je me pose est de de savoir si c’est possible ou pas et, si c'est possible, pourquoi ?

En théorie, dans ces phrases on doit dire « On a trouvé... » et « On a vu... »

Est-il possible aussi que, pendant tout ce temps, je n’aie pas compris ?

Comment: ***On*** peut remplacer à peu près toutes les personnes du singulier ou du pluriel, mais il se conjugue **toujours** à la troisième personne du singulier. ***On avez*** est donc impossible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Est-il possible que votre professeur ait utilisé « avait » au lieu de « avez » ? La conjugaison « On avait vu » est au *plus-que-parfait* qui indique une action qui s'est passée avant une autre action, elle-même située dans le passé.

Pour cette raison, l'utilisation du *plus-que-parfait* est souvent suivie par une autre phrase au *passé composé* ou l'*imparfait*.

Avec certains accents, ces mots sont parfois difficiles à distinguer.

Answer (score 0):

> On avez trouvé ce résultat

Selon moi ce n'est pas correct. « On a trouvé; vous avez trouvé; nous avons trouvé  » sont corrects. Je ne sais pas comment expliquer la faute que votre professeur a faite.

Comment: Le professeur n'a pas fait de faute, il a simplement dit "avait" et pas "avez".

Comment: J'ai bien compris après avoir vu la réponse de @DPenner1. N'ayant pas le français comme langue maternelle, je n'y ai pas réfléchi. Peut-être il fallait que je ne répondisse pas du tout:-)!

Comment: *Peut-être **eût-il fallu** que tu ne répondisses pas du tout !*

Comment: @jlliagre :   Peut-être eût-il fallu ??? Oui ! C'est le conditionnel du passé. La forme littéraire appropriée...Je pense devoir travailler la grammaire ! Peut-être aurait-il fallu que je n'aie pas employé lesdits tenses littéraires :-)! (J'espère écrire correctement maintenant).

Comment: *tenses* -> temps ;-)